# Unable to remove Virtual Network in Azure - "virtual network is in user"

Tags: azure

I have been working with a Resource Group (RG) in Azure for a while. Given it's not necessary any more, today I decided to delete it.

All the resources were deleted, but a Virtual Network. No matter what methods I tried (az cli, powershell, Portal), the error message is the same:

`Virtual Network /subscriptions/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/resourceGroups/rg-myrg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-myvnet is in use. (Code: VnetInUse)`

It may seem clear what is happening. However, right now, the only resource in the RG is the virtual network I'm trying to delete. All the other resources were deleted with no problems.

This VM had a bunch of subnets, and after some try and error and could delete all, but 1 subnet. The output message when trying to delete this subnet, doesn't give too much information. Nothing more than `Failed to delete subnet <SUBNET_NAME>. An error has occurred.`

Of course, I could just create a new RG with a different name, but one of the requirements is to keep the name.

Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed? Is there a way to force the RG deletion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the resource group you'll need to disconnect the resource that is using the virtual network so the vnet can be removed.

You'll want to determine what resource is using the subnet.  It may be a legacy resource that can also be removed, or it may be something you want to keep.  If you want to keep the resource that is using the subnet you'll need to create the subnet in a separate (or new) vnet, disconnect the resource, then reconnect it to the new subnet.

That should allow you to remove the subnet, vnet, and original resource group.

You can determine what resource is using your subnet/vnet by using the following API call:  `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{virtualNetworkName}}?api-version=2020-07-01`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree with you on the need of removing everything that depends on the VNet. However, it's not the case right now. The RG has nothing more than this VNet, even tough, it keeps saying that the VNet is in use. I use the Management API for trying to discover what would be "locking" the VNet. Nothing seems to do so. Actually, the problem is how to remove the only remaining subnet on this VNet.

Comment: If there's not a resource in another resource group that is using the subnet, you might try this too:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/75985/unable-to-delete-the-subnet-in-azure